# Have the parents or grandparents of Kol & Nat Skywalker been revealed?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Within the Legends canon, the "[Star Wars: Legacy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Legacy)" comic series introduced us to the grey Jedi Cade Skywalker. His father, [Kol Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kol_Skywalker), and uncle, Nat Skywalker, were apparently the grandsons of Ben Skywalker (and therefore the great-grandsons of Luke).

**Has the name of their father (Ben Skywalker's son) been revealed in Legends canon?**

Comment: If Kol is three generations from Luke, then Luke is Kol's great grandfather meaning their dad was the son of Ben Skywalker.

Comment: @Alarion I read it as three generations of Skywalker's not the _immediate_ three generations below Luke

Comment: "Three generations descended form Luke Skywalker himself". Three generations of descendants. Son -> Grandson -> Great-Grandson. Luke is Kol's Great-Grandfather.

Comment: Essentially, this question is asking, "Who is Ben Skywalker's son?"

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - you are correct, so there's only one missing generation, not two. Updated question to reflect that.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo - I am unable to find the source of your quote "three generations descended..." Would you be willing to provide that? It looks like that may change my answer.

Comment: I was just quoting the OP. The question has since been edited and what I was referring to has been removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There are an "undefined number of generations" between Ben and Kol.

The most information we have is that:

> A descendant of the legendary Jedi Grand Master Luke Skywalker, Kol
>   Skywalker was raised as a Jedi and trained to wield the Force.
>   <sub>[Kol Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kol_Skywalker)</sub>

The [Skywalker Family](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Skywalker_family) Tree (Legends) on Wookieepedia says the same thing. Not an authoritative source, but certainly a trusted one.

[image]

Comment: "Unkown female" may be Vestara Khai. We'll never know.

Comment: There's roughly 70 years from the time that Ben met Vestara to when Kol Skywalker was born, so it's going to be somewhere between two and four generations. But I'll go back through my Legacy trades and see if I can find where the "three generations descended" bit came from.